# Redis nodes.conf file locked?

Tags: redis, redis-cluster

I am following this tutorial to create a Redis cluster:

http://redis.io/topics/cluster-tutorial

In this tutorial I need to run several redis-server instances on port 7000 through 7005. However after I run the first instance successfully and try to run the second instance the nodes.conf file seems to be locked and I get the following error message:

"Sorry, the cluster configuration file nodes.conf is already used by a different Redis Cluster node. Please make sure that different nodes use different cluster configuration files."

Do I need a separate nodes.conf for every server instance? Or do I need a separate redis-server executable in each instance directory and run it from there?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The tutorial suggests you to use separated folders for each instance configuration, so each instance will also generate the nodes.conf on its own folder.

> Create a redis.conf file inside each of the directories, from 7000 to
>   7005.

You need to have the .conf files on separated folders for each instance, and the executable must be ran from that folders.
Assuming you have the redis-server on `/tmp/redis-cluster/`, and the redis.conf on each `/tmp/redis-cluster/700x` folder:

```
cd /tmp/redis-cluster/7000
../redis-server ./redis.conf
```

This way the nodes.conf will be generated on the current folder 7000.

Note that you must first issue a `cd` to change the current directory, and from that folder execute the redis-server that is one folder up (../)

Comment: This is exactly what I do. The problem is that the redis-server is outside the 7000, etc. directories and the nodes.conf file which it uses for the cluster configuration is shared when the different servers are started. So I think the tutorial should be edited because the way it is described it does not work.

Comment: I don't think this the problem is in the tutorial. Many of us has followed the tutorial without any problem. Can you share your folder structure and how do you *exactly* run the instances?

Comment: I have the redis-server in a folder /tmp/redis-cluster. Then I have the different redis.conf files in these folders: /tmp/redis-cluster/7000, /tmp/redis-cluster/7001, /tmp/redis-cluster/7002, /tmp/redis-cluster/7003, /tmp/redis-cluster/7004, /tmp/redis-cluster/7005. Then I run each server with these commands /tmp/redis-cluster/redis-server ./7000/redis.conf, etc. Once the cluster is created, when I try to start the servers again they start complaining about a lock on the nodes.conf file, which is located in the /tmp/redis-cluster directory.

Comment: You should run the instances like this: `cd /tmp/redis-cluster/7000` `../redis-server ./redis.conf`. I just edited my answer.

Comment: This worked! I did not realize that the current directory will be one where the server will generate the nodes.conf. Thanks.

Comment: Yes, actually is generated on the [Current Working Directory](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/74249/what-does-it-mean-each-process-has-a-current-directory) of the `redis-server` process.